# transparent text over background-image

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'd like to know how you would create the effect of the background-image showing under the text.
Here's an example: [chevalblanc.com](http://www.chevalblanc.com/randheli/en/). I imagine two `<sections>`, the first one has that cut out text background image, the second section has a photo or something in the background.
I noticed they used a png where they "cut out" the letters and used it as background, but how do you create the scrolling effect?

Update: I found out how to do it, actually it's pretty easy. You have to give two background images to your `<section>`or `<div>` and you set the image you want to have in the very background "fixed".
 For Example: 
`.yoursection { width: xx %; height: xx %;
background-image: url(images/backgroundimage.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed, url(images/foregroundimage.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}`

Worked fine for me.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: This is Parallax scrolling. You can read a tutorial here with demos http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/

Comment: its not text its a solid image http://www.chevalblanc.com/randheli/medias/images/intro/1400/maskintro-en.png

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra
I was wondering about how to achieve the scrolling effect between two background-images. If I wanted something like [this](http://www.chevalblanc.com/randheli/en/) I had to place a picture in the background and the image which has the transparent text in it above that picture. So far, so good. How would you scroll one image above another within one HTML `<section>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to the CSS 3D transforms would be to use parallax scrolling (an example of which below)

```
http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/
```

Basically, with Skrollr you can transform. scale, skew and rotate the heck out of any element, all done in layers and transitioning is smooth. So essentially I would say just find a tutorial about the usage of Skrollr (or just experiment), create your elements, which in this instance would be a background with transparent text, and then another background image beneath the transparent text background element.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely crafted with combination of CSS3 and Jquery. Yes I can see they are using png transparent mask (mask05.png). To answer your question how the scrolling is achieved please read through http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/

Comment: Also, please read through how to use CSS3 transition-timing-function @ http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/

Answer (score 0):

the transparent text you are watching it is not text its a solid image

here is a link for it

http://www.chevalblanc.com/randheli/medias/images/intro/1400/maskintro-en.png

and for scrolling there is a plugin called [**snapscroll**](https://github.com/wtm/jquery.snapscroll)

Comment: Thanks for the clue about the plugin.